# Magento2 - Which Phtml file controls img alt?

Tags: magento2, image

which file in magento 2 controls the img alt description for the front-end?

i already looked at the `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml` file, but there is no alt in it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For Product Image at frontend :**

> **magento_root_directory/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/image.phtml**

**For Product Gallery Image at Frontend :**

> **magento_root_directory/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/gallery.phtml**

Comment: module-catalog in stead of module_catalog

Comment: @Ronny - Edited thanks for suggestion - Happy to help and keep helping :)

Comment: do you also know file for the product image on the product page?

Comment: i guess its on same location file name - image_with_borders.phtml

Comment: that is not the one i am looking for .... in the image_with_borders the class is `class="product-image-photo"` but in my magento it is `class="fotorama__img"` do you which phtml file is that?